# Airflow - BashOperator - error running 2 CLI commands

Tags: python, bash, npm, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Airflow 2.0.1.

I have BashOperator task in DAG which looks like this:

```
proxy_update_getProxies = BashOperator(
    task_id='proxy_update_getProxies',
    bash_command="scripts/proxies-update-get.sh",
    dag=dag)
```

`scripts` folder is in `dag` folder so according to documentation it should be ok to run it like this.

`proxies-update-get.sh` script contains 2 lines:

```
proxy-lists updateGeoIpData --license-key Y00qKC2A9ZoWVXJW
proxy-lists getProxies --protocols="https" --output-format="txt" --output-file="httpsproxies.txt"
```

`proxy-lists` is `nmp` package which can be run with these 2 commands from CLI to update and get list of proxies.
Script works fine from any folder so `$PATH` should not be problem yet I get this error:

```
can't open file 'proxy-lists': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running with the full path for `proxy-lists`, and/or with `./proxy-lists`. If either of these work, you know it's a problem with `$PATH`.

Comment: Keep in mind that your `$PATH` settings may not be transferred to `BashOperator`. I don't know how the operator works (I would expect it does take into account your path settings), but this may be an issue.

Comment: And the same question/check as my first comment, for the "new" script/package?

Comment: I don't know npm very well, but "running" packages sound odd: normally, one uses/imports packages, and runs a (wrapper) script that uses the package.

Comment: @00 package supports CLI commands that runs normally in bash and via bash script.

Comment: Yes, but did you try the suggestions from my first comment?

Comment: The airflow _bash_ user does not have access to proxy-lists. It does not see installed, either share it with it or you can start the bash script with the installation itself, and after that you can just run it.

Comment: @00 thank you for your comments which helped me to resolve issue. I just used full path to the CLI script and it worked.

Comment: @PeterRing thank you for your comments which helped me to resolve issue. I just used full path to the CLI script and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@00** and **@PeterRing**.

I just used full path to the node CLI script in my bash script and it worked fine:

```
/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/proxy-lists/cli.js updateGeoIpData --license-key hshshhshshshsh
/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/proxy-lists/cli.js getProxies --protocols="https" --output-format="txt" --output-file="/home/username/airflow/dags/scripts/httpsproxies.txt"
```